# Does VIM have a "caller()" built-in function like Perl?

Tags: vim

I'l looking for a way to print the calling function during execution of a VIM script (e.g., a stack trace), similar to the `caller()` support in Perl.

Does VIM have such built-in support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. It's definitively not a built-in feature however. I've hacked it by throwing an exception and decoding the `v:throwpoint`. I don't reproduce the code here as it's complex enough and IMO out of scope for SO.

Everything can be found in [`lh#exception#callstack()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/exception.vim)

If you look closely, you'll see that each function in the call stack is extracted, searched among the `scriptnames` in order to deduce the exact line(s) of code where the call(s) happened. I also avoid fetching an information I already have.

I've used it to define a logging feature that fills the quickfix windows with current call point.